# ¿Por qué se genera un bucle infinito?

Tags: python

estoy haciendo un bucle while sencillo que añade a una lista caracteres, y que cuando ya no se quieren introducir más, se digite un espacio en blanco.

```
entrada = ''
lista = []

while(entrada != "\n"):
    entrada = input("Digite un caracter (presione Enter para acabar): ")
    lista.append(entrada)
```

No entiendo porque entra en un bucle infinito, no se si es porque no es un el carácter salto de línea.

Comment: porque no importa lo que escribas con el teclado siempre sera diferente a "\n" por lo que es True y seguira en el ciclo, dado que \n es un salto de linea que no se puede generar mediante el teclado

Comment: Si el usuario pulsa un retorno de carro ante un `input()` , el programa recibirá una cadena vacía y no un `"\n"`, porque `input()` elimina el fin de línea antes de retornar al programa.

Comment: Buen día, si la respuesta te sirvió por favor acéptala, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a sus preguntas y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. Lectura recomendada [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Si únicamente revisas la condición en el `while` como ha sido propuesto en la otra respuesta e inicializamos `entrada` con `None` siempre se va a agregar un `string` vacío al final de la lista.

Ejemplo del problema al utilizar la comparación en el `while`:

```
entrada = None
lista = []

while(entrada != ""):
    entrada = input("Digite un caracter (presione Enter para acabar): ")
    print(entrada)
    lista.append(entrada)
print(lista)
```

Muestra del funcionamiento:

```
Digite un caracter (presione Enter para acabar):  a
a
Digite un caracter (presione Enter para acabar):  b
b
Digite un caracter (presione Enter para acabar):  

['a', 'b', '']
```

Como puedes ver, al final de la lista se agregó el `string` vacío que se genera al únicamente presionar "Enter" sin ningún caracter.

Lo que puedes hacer es hacer un ciclo infinito y adentro del `while` revisar el valor de `entrada`, si es un `string` vacío entonces terminar el `while` utilizando `break`.

Ejemplo completo:

```
entrada = None
lista = []

while(True):
    entrada = input("Digite un caracter (presione Enter para acabar): ")
    if entrada == '':
        break
        
    lista.append(entrada)
print(lista)
```

Muestra del funcionamiento:

```
Digite un caracter (presione Enter para acabar):  a
Digite un caracter (presione Enter para acabar):  b
Digite un caracter (presione Enter para acabar):  
['a', 'b']
```

**Nota adicional:** En el texto se solicita al usuario ingresar un caracter, pero en el código que pusiste no hay nada que impida al usuario escribir frases completas por lo que tendrías que pensar como limitar el tamaño del `string` de entrada para que acepte únicamente un solo caracter.